# How many distinct squares, with sides on the grid lines of the checkerboard and containing at least 5 black squares, can be drawn on the checkerboard?

Tags: combinatorics

An 8 by 8 checkerboard has alternating black and white squares. How many distinct squares, with sides on the grid lines of the checkerboard (horizontal and vertical) and containing at least 5 black squares, can be drawn on the checkerboard?

[image: The Checkerboard]

I tried this approach when the problem was slightly different. It was when it said containing at least **4** squares.

Could someone tell me the solution or give me a hint?

Below is my answer to the different problem:

no 2x2 squares have 4 black squares

all 3x3 squares have at least 4 black squares, as do all 4x4, 5x5, 6x6, 7x7, and 8x8 squares.

there are 6x6=36 3x3 squares

there are 5x5=25 4x4 squares

there are 4x4=16 5x5 squares

there are 3x3=9  6x6 squares

there are 2x2=4  7x7 squares

there is   1          8x8 square

Summing we get 91 squares

But I don;t know how to do it for this problem. Could someone tell me how?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that any square with side length at least $4$ will have at least $5$ black squares.  However, only those $3 \times 3$ squares with a black square in its lower-left corner will contain at least $5$ black squares (in fact, it will contain exactly five black squares).  By symmetry, only half the $3 \times 3$ squares on the checkerboard satisfy this condition.

Observe that there are $(9 - k)^2$ squares of side length $k$, $1 \leq k \leq 8$ on the checkerboard since the lower left vertex of the square must be located on one of the first $9 - k$ horizontal grid lines and one of the first $9 - k$ vertical grid lines.

Hence, the number of squares which may be drawn on the checkerboard which contain at least $5$ black squares is
$$\frac{1}{2}(9 - 3)^2 + \sum_{k = 4}^{9} (9 - k)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 6^2 + 5^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 73$$

Comment: No 1times1 squares or 2times2 squares contain five black squares. Every square which is 4times4 or larger does. However, a 3times3 square will only contain 5 black squares if its upper left corner is black. We can choose the upper left corner of a 3times3 square in 6*6=36 ways, but for only half of these squares will the upper left corner be black. Therefore, there are 36/2=18 3times3 squares containing at least 5 black squares. We can choose the position of the upper left square of a 4times4 square in 5*5=25 ways, so there are 25 4times4 squares. Con;t below

Comment: Similarly, there are 16 5times5 squares, 9 6times6 squares, 4 7times7 squares, and 1 8times8 square. There are a total of 18+25+16+9+4+1=73 squares containing at least 5 black squares.

Comment: What you said in the comments is correct.